# comparing one array element with the next element to find what is the biggest element

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a way to iterating while comparing the element with the next element to find what is the biggest element in the array. But, the output i want keep repeating as much as the loop run.

```
int main(){
    int array[4];

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    for (int i:array){
        for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++){
            if (i < array[j]){
               break;
            }
            if (i > array[j] ){
                cout << i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following [program](https://onlinegdb.com/vK8n9RCDZ) to find the biggest element in the array. Note that there is **no need** to use two for loops as you did in your code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[4] = {1,10, 13, 2};
    
    int arraySize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);//note that you can also use std::size() with C++17 
    
    int startingValue = array[0];
    
    for(int i = 1; i < arraySize; ++i)//start from 1 instead of 0 since we already have array[0]
    {
        if(array[i] > startingValue)
        {
            startingValue = array[i];
        }
    }


    //print out the biggest value 
    std::cout<<"the biggest element in the array is: "<<startingValue<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Your program is reapeating output because you have the `cout` inside the `if` which is satisfied multiple times(depending upon how big the array is and what elements it contains). For example, if you try your example on the array `int array[] = {23,2,13,6,52,9,3,78};` then the output of your program will be `2323231313652525293787878` . So the output is reapeating more than 2 times. You can instead use the version i gave that uses only 1 for loop and prints the correct biggest element only once.

**Note** that you can also use `std::size` with C++17 while `sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)` works with all C++ versions.